# Cannot save table in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have added a column to a table in SQL Server 2005. When I attempt to save it, I get this message:

> Saving changes is not permitted. The
>   change you have made require the
>   following tables to be dropped and
>   re-created. You have either made
>   changes to a table that can't be
>   re-created or enabled the option
>   Prevent saving changes that require
>   the table to be re-created.

The column I added was nothing special, a nullable nvarchar(11) with no index or constraints. I have never seen this problem before, and have changed the table many times earlier.

Anyone know what's going on, and where I should look for the mentioned option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

It was actually an option in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 (which I am using, even though the DB in question is 2005), and not in the DB or server instance as I expected.

The option is exactly as stated in the error message "Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created". I found it in Management Studio under Tools -> Options -> Designers, and it is obviously enabled by default. A very strange default indeed!

Comment: They added it because this actually results in Management Studio selecting the data in the table into a temp table, dropping the table and recreating it, then reinserting the data back in from the temp table.  Not ideal in many situations.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably coming up because you aren't putting the column at the end of the table.  Putting a column in the middle of the table causes the table to be dropped and recreated.